# Facebook login in Android App error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I am trying out the Facebook integration with Android studio and it isn't a cool ride.I found so many errors which i have cleared and so much ambiguity in the facebook developers site https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

so this is my MainActivity.java

```
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


    import android.os.Bundle;




    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private MainFragment mainFragment;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if(savedInstanceState==null) {
                mainFragment = new MainFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();

            }
            else
            {
                mainFragment=(MainFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);



            }
        }}
```

and another class called MainFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        return view;
    }


}
```

and this is xml code just as mentioned in facebook site

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and it compiles and when i run it it installs in android virtual device and force closes itself...
 here is the logcat

```
02-09 10:21:30.561    1796-1796/com.pezfroll.faceb D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-09 10:21:30.585    1796-1796/com.pezfroll.faceb D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9832990, tid 1796
02-09 10:21:30.673    1796-1796/com.pezfroll.faceb D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-09 10:21:30.677    1796-1796/com.pezfroll.faceb D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-09 10:21:31.017    1796-1796/com.pezfroll.faceb W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-09 10:21:31.021    1796-1796/com.pezfroll.faceb E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-09 10:21:31.085    1796-1796/com.pezfroll.faceb E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-09 10:21:31.089    1796-1796/com.pezfroll.faceb D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-09 10:21:31.213    1796-1810/com.pezfroll.faceb W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bc3648)
02-09 10:21:32.129    1796-1810/com.pezfroll.faceb E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911)
            at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:673)
            at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:678)
            at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:675)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-09 10:21:50.613    1796-1810/com.pezfroll.faceb I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1796 SIG: 9
```

I havent even added the behaviour and it still forcecloses

Comment: BTW i added the code in gradle before starting the code as mentioned in the site.

Comment: Do you have your app ID specified in the AndroidManifest.xml and strings.xml as recommended in the getting started docs?

Comment: It's new Android studio  so all I have to do is add some code in gradle

Comment: The login button needs your app ID to be specified, so the "Then add your Facebook App ID into your project's strings file" and "Update your Android Manifest" sections under the Eclipse section are also necessary. I will update the docs to reflect that.

Comment: What you said was correct but that's for eclipse and i am using android studio and recently facebook developers updated their page to work on android studio and now the process is different. I already provided the link for it please check it ..

Comment: I work on the SDK as well as the documentation. Please follow the steps in the getting started guide for Android Studios - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#androidstudio and add your app ID into the strings.xml and AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I'm sorry I have mistaken you... Thanks I will try that and will tell you the same.. Thank you so much.. I owe you

Comment: @MingLi I have a small doubt... when i enter compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1' .. should i be given 3.23.0 because thats the facebook sdk version im using right now

Answer (score 0):

The entire guide should be followed as Ming Li stated.

The only issue i had with the instructions is that it makes reference to an application tab

here:
5. In the Application tab, add new meta-data with the name com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId and the value @string/facebook_app_id.

It should have stated :
5. In the **Application Node within the AndroidManifest**, add new meta-data with the name com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId and the value @string/facebook_app_id.

There is also another fundamental aspect to the code which could cause this.
If you are using android studio you may realize in your **MainFragment** the note at the to is as below:

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MainFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */

Thats right, **OnFragmentInteractionListener** must be **implemented** in the **MainActivity** as follows:

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {...Class code inside here...}

And the **MainActivity** class must **Override** the **onFragmentInteraction** Method as follows:

@Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        mainFragment.onButtonPressed(uri);
    }